# Can you help me identify the maker of this shower door roller?

Tags: doors, shower

I've a broken roller on my shower door. I'm looking for replacement parts but I can't identify the maker of the piece so it makes the search a bit harder. I post a picture of the intact piece. Any of you have an idea of the maker ?

Thanks

[image: Shower door roller]

Comment: I would take it to a plumbing or speciality store.

Comment: I tried a couple places but no luck so far.

Comment: If you get a picture of this without your hand, google images has a function to search by image. Go to http://google.com/imghp then click the little camera next to the search icon, and upload the image there. Then scroll down and click "Visually similar images"

Comment: Tried it with no success but I finally found the maker of the part with a helpful men in a local plumming shop. For the record, it's made by Fleurco  (http://www.fleurco.com/)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the maker of the part with an helpful men in a local plumming shop. For the record, it's made by Fleurco (fleurco.com)

Thanks for your help